# Plotting using decimals and representing tooltip labels in percentage

Tags: r, ggplot2, tooltip, plotly, percentage

I wish to plot the line chart using ggplotly and represent the numbers in percentage. So the ggplot command before **or** represents the figures in percentages and after **or** in decimals. The plots appear to be different. How can I make the plot using decimals and represent the tool tip labels in percentages?

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
library(devtools)
library(proto)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(gapminder)
library(stringr)
library(broom)
library(mnormt)

dat1 <- data.frame(
sex = factor(c("Female","Female","Male","Male")),
time = factor(c("Lunch","Dinner","Lunch","Dinner"), 
levels=c("Lunch","Dinner")),
total_bill = c(13.53, 16.81, 16.24, 17.42)
total_bill_pr = sprintf("%.0f%%", 100 * total_bill)
)

# Map sex to different point shape, and use larger points
p <- ggplot(data=dat1, aes(x=time, y=total_bill_pr, group=sex, shape=sex)) +
geom_line() +
geom_point()

p <- ggplotly(p)
p
```

**or**

```
 # Map sex to different point shape, and use larger points
p <- ggplot(data=dat1, aes(x=time, y=total_bill, group=sex, shape=sex)) +
geom_line() +
geom_point()

p <- ggplotly(p)
p
```

Comment: `total_bill_pr` is a factor, not a numeric variable! This is why you get two different plots.

Comment: Thank you so much Marco for replying, I would highly appreciate if you can correct this code as I have tried doing that but am not able to get it. the total_bill_pr is a character type variable that I see using str(total_bill_pr).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a solution for your problem:

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)

total_bill = c(13.53, 16.81, 16.24, 17.42)
dat1 <- data.frame(
sex = factor(c("Female","Female","Male","Male")),
time = factor(c("Lunch","Dinner","Lunch","Dinner"), levels=c("Lunch","Dinner")),
total_bill_no_pr = total_bill,
total_bill = sprintf("%.2f%%", total_bill)
)

# Use an additional "label" aesthetic
p <- ggplot(data=dat1, aes(x=time, y=total_bill_no_pr, 
            group=sex, shape=sex, label=total_bill)) +
     geom_line() + geom_point() + ylab("Total bill") + xlab("Time")

# Specify which aesthetic mappings to show in the tooltip 
p <- ggplotly(p, tooltip = c("x", "label", "group"))
p
```

[image]

A more flexible solution is:

```
# Use an additional "text" aesthetic
p <- ggplot(data=dat1, aes(x=time, y=total_bill_no_pr, group=sex, shape=sex,
            text=paste("Time:",time,"<br />Total bill:",total_bill,"<br />Sex:",sex))) +
     geom_line() + geom_point() + ylab("Total bill") + xlab("Time")

# Specify to show only the "text" aesthetic in the tooltip 
p <- ggplotly(p, tooltip = c("text"))
p
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you So much pal, it's very illustrative and precise.

Comment: I liked the second solution...very easy. Thanks!